# Error occurs when I put cox.zph into a new function

Tags: r

I am trying to write an R function to output statistical tests and graphical diagnostics for testing proportional hazards assumptions at the same time.
Concretely, I want to put survival::cox.zph and survival::coxph into an R function as following.

```
  library(survival)
  data(veteran)

  PH_assumption0 <- function(phmodel,phdata){
  zph <-  survival::cox.zph(survival::coxph(phmodel,
                                            data   = phdata))
  print(zph)
  survminer::ggcoxzph(zph)
  }

  PH_assumption0(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + age, veteran)
```

But I failed. There was an error: Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'phdata' not found
Called from: is.data.frame(data).

I tried to reduce the arguments (phmodel,phdata) in the function as following:

```
    PH_assumption1 <- function(phdata){
    zph <-  survival::cox.zph(survival::coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + age,
                                    data   = phdata))
    print(zph)
    survminer::ggcoxzph(zph)
    }
    PH_assumption1(veteran)

    PH_assumption2 <- function(phmodel){
    zph <-  survival::cox.zph(survival::coxph(phmodel,
                                           data   = veteran))
    print(zph)
    survminer::ggcoxzph(zph)
    }
    PH_assumption2(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + age)
```

Both of them worked, but I don't know why. Could you help me to understand why two arguments does not work but one does? Thank you very much.

[output in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Zgi.png)

Comment: In `PH_assumption0`, you don’t provide a value for the `phdata` argument. It’s a simple typo.

Comment: Dear @Limey, many thanks for your quick and kind answer. It is an edit error. Sorry for that. However, it still does not work after revising this mistake. Could you give me further help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

PH_assumption0 <- function(phmodel,phdata){
  zph <-  survival::cox.zph(survival::coxph(phmodel,
                                            data = phdata))
  print(zph)
  survminer::ggcoxzph(zph)
}
phdata <<- veteran
PH_assumption0(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + age, veteran)
```

Worked through the backtrace, and phdata is not being passed to is.data.frame, so as a work around, I did a super assignment. Added the survminer library call. Deleted the data call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful methods, it works and give me a good revelation for building function.